# Complex Divs (float/clear) - Two main columns + smaller internal columns

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have the following basic layout:

```
<div id="sidebar" style="float: left; width: 250px; display block;"></div>
<div id="maincontent"></div>
```

Fairly self explanatory - on the left I have navigation stuff and info, and the rest of the page is the main content.

I have a user control for which I'm using the following:

```
<div id="weather-data">
    <div id="today" style="float: left;"></div>
    <div id="tomorrow" style="float: left;"></div>
    <div id="etc" style="float: left;"></div>
</div>
```

Each block displays an image and some text for the daily weather.

All the above displays fine, but the problem is as such:

The height of the sidebar is (as an example) 400px high. The **maincontent** div houses a child div **weather-data** which is 200px high. Within the **weather-data** div are smaller divs floated to the left.

Below the **weather-data** div I want some text. This is where the difficulty lies.

If I clear the float after **weather-data** then it also clears the sidebar causing a big chunk of whitespace.

```
<div class="weather-data">
    <div id="today" style="float: left;"></div>
    <div id="tomorrow" style="float: left;"></div>
    <div id="etc" style="float: left;"></div>

    <div style="clear: left;"></div>
</div>
```

Some crude diagrams...

What I want:

```
[@@@][##########################]
[@@@][##########################]
[@@@][##########################]
[@@@][ Additional text          ]
[@@@][                          ]
[@@@][                          ]
[   ][                          ]
```

What I get:

```
[@@@][##########################]
[@@@][##########################]
[@@@][##########################]
[@@@][                          ]
[@@@][                          ]
[@@@][                          ]
[   ][ Additional text          ] <-- Additional text jumps down below the sibebar content :o(
```

Where @ is **sidebar** content, # is the **weather-data** div collection.

Slight update... setting **overflow: hidden;** on the weather-data div works, but isn't that risky?

Comment: this is slightly unclear. can you draw in simple box form the layout you are looking for?

Comment: when you say "content" which div are you refering to?

Comment: it sounds like you need to put a float on the `content` div.

Comment: I've had a go at making it clearer, but it's 8.15pm, I'm still at work, and need to go home...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `overflow: hidden`, it will not clip away your content as long you don't specify a height for the div with this property.

Answer (score 0):

Try to append `<div style="clear:both"></div>` at the end of the "weather-data" div.

Comment: The trouble with that is it clears the float left of the leftbar/sidebar which is higher than the main content, leaving whitespace.

Comment: OK, I understand you problem now. Could you fix the height of the weather-data div in order for the "additional text" to stay below the weather-data div?