# br won't make a new line

Tags: html, css, forms

The br tag in HTML doesn't make a new line. I have a div which has two divs inside it. The divs inside are floating left and right. I used br twice to make a new line for the submit button below it and to make a visible space in between them but it wouldn't budge. I tried making a div for the submit button too and tried using CSS to edit it but it still wouldn't work.

```css
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

.mainform
{
    width: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: gray;
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.inputText1
{
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.inputText2
{
    margin-left: 12px;
}

.from
{
    margin-top: -20px;
}

.firstStop
{
    float:left;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.secondStop
{
    float: right;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainform">
    <div class="header"><h2 align="center">Metro Rail Transit Fare</h2></div>
    <div class="from"><p align="center">(North Avenue Station)</p></div>
    <form method="POST" action="InformationPath">
        Passenger First Name: <input type="text" name="first" class="inputText1" />
        <br>
        Passenger Last Name: <input type="text" name="last" class="inputText2" />
    <br>
    <br>
    Destination:
    <br>
        <div class="stops">
            <div class="firstStop">
                Stop 1: <input type="radio" name="destination" value="1,Quezon Avenue"/> Quezon Avenue 
                <br>
                Stop 2: <input type="radio" name="destination" value="2,Cubao"/> Cubao 
                <br>
                Stop 3: <input type="radio" name="destination" value="3,Ortigas"/> Ortigas 
                <br>
                Stop 4: <input type="radio" name="destination" value="4,Boni Avenue"/> Boni Avenue 
                <br>
                Stop 5: <input type="radio" name="destination" value="5,Buendia"/>Buendia 
                <br>
                Stop 6: <input type="radio" name="destination" value="6,Magallanes"/> Magallanes
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="secondStop">
                <input type="radio" name="destination" value="1,GMA Kamuning"/>GMA Kamuning
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="destination" value="2,Santolan" /> Santolan
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="destination" value="3,Shaw Boulevard"/>  Shaw Boulevard
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="destination" value="4,Guadalupe"/>  Guadalupe
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="destination" value="5,Ayala"/> Ayala
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="destination" value="6,Taft Avenue"/> Taft Avenue
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: everything inside the `<form>`?

Comment: try `<input style="clear:both" ...>` so it'll get shoved down BELOW your floated divs.

Comment: You could easily use css to achieve this. BR tag are meant for text only, as in breaking a line to start a new paragraph, and not pushing html elements. Use proper coding methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already added a class to your button, why not using it in your css?

```
.button {
   display: inline-block;
   margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: You should still remove the line breaks in fairness

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS to get the button to appear below the text forms, and `<br>` should only be used for moving down lines of text, not for aligning or styling.

Remove the `<br>` tags and add this to your CSS:

```
input.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

Then change the line of your Submit button to this:

```
<input class="button clear" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the layout of your divs - not the input.

`.stops` should be fixed as its contents are floated it should have the responsibility to rectify page flow. Floated elements "fall out" of the page flow much like `position:absolute` elements.

You should try:

```
.stops {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

This will allow the surrounding div to "push" the button to where it should be in the page flow.

See also: [Complex Divs (float/clear) - Two main columns + smaller internal columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835661/complex-divs-float-clear-two-main-columns-smaller-internal-columns)